# Android Support Jar not found Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

hello im getting this error from eclipse. i tryed nearly everthing to fix it but soemwhat it keeps happening.

first i tryed to reinstall google support library's. i did it several times

[2017-03-23 22:21:50 - Android Support Jar not found:] C:\Windows\System32\v4\android-support-v4.jar

this is the error im getting. before this i was getting same error with this

[2017-03-23 22:21:50 - Android Support Jar not found:] C:\bla bla bla\destop\v4\android-support-v4.jar

so it was looking for jar at desktop.

Comment: You should use Android Studio, this is the official IDE for Android

Comment: well im in a bit hurry also new to android development, right now configuring android studio